# Can't set bridges for tor, [warn] Key digest for Bridge is wrong length

Tags: lubuntu, tor

I want to set bridges for tor, but I can't, the problem is when I run

```
$tor
```

command, I get this error:

```
May 27 19:02:36.100 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.20 (git-0d50b03673670de6) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1f.
May 27 19:02:36.100 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
May 27 19:02:36.100 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 27 19:02:36.105 [warn] Key digest for Bridge is wrong length.
May 27 19:02:36.105 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Bridge line did not parse. See logs for details.
May 27 19:02:36.105 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

The keys work when I use them on ubuntu 16.04 with tor version 0.2.7
but in lubuntu 14.04, I have tor version 0.2.4(I wrote this because I think there might be a bug in this version)

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please try this command before `sudo service tor restart` , and then see this command output `tail -f /var/log/tor/log` . If `[notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done` is shown,  it's mean that your bridges sets successful.

Comment: The result is the same error, key digest for Bridge is wrong length

Comment: The bad is with your torrc file. What's the output of this command `cat /etc/tor/torrc`

Comment: [here](https://paste.ubuntu.ir/yfsm) is my torrc file

Comment: ok !  U can use my torrc file instead of yours https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/24679605/

Comment: I was trying another version of tor and I accidentally pasted the wrong torrc file, I editted the link now, you can see the link again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59411/discussion-between-ali-and-mohammad-ganji).